# How do I create a persistent button on the bottom of a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I have a master / detail based iPhone app. Without using a tabbed navigation style application, how do I create a persistent button at the bottom of the navigation controller ( I want it on every view ). Please wireframe ( its the plus button ). I've tried adding a button bar item to the toolbar at the bottom, but for some reason it won't show up. I'm using xcode 8 and ios 10.

[image]

for reference I created a custom navigation controller class and inserted the following code

```
#import "MainNavigationController.h"

@interface MainNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation MainNavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Testing");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *myButton1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"button 1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toolbarButtonPressed1:)];
    [buttonsArray addObject:myButton1];
    UIBarButtonItem *myButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"button 2" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toolbarButtonPressed2:)];
    [buttonsArray addObject:myButton2];
    [self setToolbarItems:buttonsArray animated:YES];

    [self.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [self.toolbar setItems: buttonsArray animated:NO];

}
```

Then I make the toolbar visible in the interface builder ... the toolbar shows and the color is set in code, but the buttons do not appear

Comment: "I've tried adding a button bar item to the toolbar at the bottom, but for some reason it won't show up" If that solution would do, you should be asking yourself what the reason _is_. Unfortunately you have elected to show no code, so it's impossible to assist.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. A navigation controller doesn't have toolbar items; its children do. You would need to set `self.navigationItem.toolbarItems` in all of this navigation controller's children. My solution below is probably better for you.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to embed your UINavigationController in a custom parent view controller. This means that the navigation controller's view is a subview of the parent view controller's view. And that means that you could add *another* subview of the parent view controller's view, the button.

Comment: The root view is actually a split view controller, what would the base class be for the parent view ?

Comment: "The root view is actually a split view controller". In that case, you could embed your split view controller in a custom parent view controller. That's not an uncommon thing to do in any case. Of course you will then have to think about how you want this interface to work on an iPad (expanded split view controller).