# Subview passes touches to subview beneath it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview

I have added a subview like so:

```
func showPlayerView2() {
    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 56)
    //let theView = myView
    let theView = PlayerView()
    theView.willMove(toParentViewController: self.navigationController)
    self.navigationController?.addChildViewController(theView)
    theView.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    theView.playPauseButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.navigationController?.view.bringSubview(toFront: theView.view)
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(theView.view)
    theView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.maxY, width: 375, height: 56)

    theView.didMove(toParentViewController: self.navigationController)
    self.view.layoutSubviews()
}
```

`PlayerView` Has a button that is supposed to print something to the screen when pressed.

Even after setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`, it still does not register touches and they pass through to the view below it. I have looked at nearly every SO question relating to this and none of the answers have worked. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to add a touch gesture to your view? Also, you can share a screenshot for additional info.

Comment: Manipulating the child view controllers, view, and subviews of a navigation controller is totally illegal. Hard to be sympathetic for any issues you may have when doing that. What's the purpose of this code?

Comment: I'm trying to add a subview to the screen that will stay throughout all screens on the navigation controller

Comment: @matt Is there a more effective way to go about this?

Comment: "trying to add a subview to the screen that will stay throughout all screens on the navigation controller" Then I think that would have been the question for you to ask / research, rather than going down a false road and then struggling to make it work. This has been asked and answered many times here. See for example my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40026622/341994

Comment: @matt Ok, that works and gets the subview showing on the screen, but whenever I click the button inside the `PlayerView` subview, it still passes the touches through to the other VC. How can I fix this now?

Comment: @matt Nevermind. I solved the issue. Thanks for your answer on the other page, will up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if your looking for a common custom navigation menu

```
  func setupPageNavigationBar(){
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.22, blue:0.22, alpha:1.0)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

        let backButton = UIButton(type:.System)
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "img_back")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal), forState: .Normal)
        backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

        let imgButton = UIButton(type:.System)
        imgButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "img_logo_bar")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal), forState: .Normal)
        imgButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)


        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems  = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton),UIBarButtonItem(customView:imgButton)]
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.goBack), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = "SOME TITLE"
        let titleLabel2 = UILabel()
        titleLabel2.text = "Some text"

        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .Left

        titleLabel2.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
        titleLabel2.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        titleLabel2.textAlignment = .Left

        let titleView = UIView()
        titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width-90, height: 50)
        //titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        titleView.addSubview(titleLabel2)
        titleLabel2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        //titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 134, height: 34)


        let viewDict = ["titleLabel":titleLabel,"titleLabel2":titleLabel2]

        titleView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[titleLabel]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
        titleView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[titleLabel2]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewDict))

        titleView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-5-[titleLabel(20)]-0-[titleLabel2(15)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewDict))

        //5+20+5+15+5
        navigationItem.titleView = titleView

        let homeButton = UIButton(type:.System)
        homeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "img_home")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal), forState: .Normal)
        homeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(customView: homeButton)
        homeButton.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(self.gotoHome), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        //CGRectMake()



    }
```

And In viewControllers

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {

        self.setupPageNavigationBar()
    }
```